# Is there an earth science discipline, or subdiscipline, that only studies magma or lava?

Tags: volcanology, volcanoes, magmatism

I know volcanologists study volcanoes. Is there a subdiscipline that only studies maga or lava? A magmatologist?

Comment: Note that there are usually two aspects to studying magmas and lavas. One is the chemical composition of the magma (i.e. what is it made from) and the other the physical (how how it is or how does it move). Both aspects are highly related, but some researches only focus on one of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps they are called [Igneous Petrologists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igneous_petrology) ?

Someone who studies magma/lava flows tends to go by Geophysicist because they inherently study continuum mechanics and fluid flow.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. An igneous petrologist studies igneous rock - which are by definition rocks that have crystallized from a silicate liquid (magma or lava.)

Comment: Do you think you could answer [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136724/26969)? Looking for someone who knows about lava...